# What are the regularly spaced spots on this piece of material on the surface of Mars?

Tags: mars, perseverance, geology

[image: Piece2]

This image is a part of the [Image of the week](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/image-of-the-week/week-70), a photo acquired by the Perseverance rover's Mastcam-Z camera and selected by public vote.
To me it seems like a piece of [styrofoam](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/styrofoam) and with a closer look one can see the regularly spaced spots on it, which spots I think can only be man-made.

Comment: A comment since it does not describe the dots, but Perserverance twitter account says it is foil from the descent stage https://twitter.com/NASAPersevere/status/1537120573314113536?s=20&t=CfSfC1rqZyF_ckJQ2dcdug

Comment: @GremlinWranger Nevertheless a clarifying answer, thank you !

Comment: "NASA finds debris from alien spacecraft"

Comment: @GremlinWranger One of the replies includes a photo of different material samples: https://twitter.com/NASAPersevere/status/1537120586081521664/photo/2 Unfortunately it's a little small so I couldn't read the labels, but the dots appear on some of the materials there.

Comment: My unsourced supposition is that it is insulation with two layers, and the dots are where the layers are joined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The material is likely part of the Mars 2020 descent stage's thermal insulation "blanket". The spots are holes that are critical for equalizing/venting the pressure inside and outside of the spacecraft during launch.

Source: [Mars Guy - Perseverance spots unexpected intruder in Mars rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzPCww-PCeg)